# I have a quadratic minimization problem such that, $e=x^TAx+x^Tb+k$, I wish to find its minima using recursive least square.

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming

I have arrived at a generic quadratic minimization problem, such that,
\begin{equation}
e=x^TAx+x^Tb+k
\end{equation}
where,$x=[x_1,x_2,x_3]^T \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $b=[\gamma,0,0]$ and $k$ is a constant.
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \alpha &0 \\
0 & 0 & -\beta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Let, 
\begin{equation}
x^*=\arg\min_x(e)
\end{equation}
clearly, $A$ is not full rank. I wish to minimize $e$ over $x$ using recursive least square, is it possible? I know it can be minimized using gradient descent but I want to know if it is feasible to minimize this quadratic using RLS? Also the reason why I am going for RLS is because, gradient descent fails when $A,b$ changes abruptly.

Comment: Choose $x=[-sign(\gamma)M,0,0]^T$, where $M$ is a large positive number. Look what happens to the objective value!

Comment: It'll be $-M|\gamma|+k$ and if $M|\gamma|>k$, then $-M|\gamma|+k<0$-- which is not desirable!

Comment: So, by increasing $M$, the objective value goes to $-\infty$ no matter what $k$ is!

Comment: But i still dont get it, can i not find arg min of e?

Comment: I mean given a fixed set of A, b and k, can't we find arg min?

Comment: Using the point that I gave you, there is no finite global optimum for this specific question. If $A$ was PSD or PD, the story was different. Maybe see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming.

Comment: What if A was a PSD?